# Force what is being given as a string parameter in php

Tags: php, string, parameters

I've searched for the answer to my problem, but I'm having trouble putting it to words. So... I'm asking here.

I have a method which is created to echo text with a given string and an error type:

```
public function output($string, $errorType) : void
{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-$errorType' role='alert'>$string</div>";
}
```

Since I'm using bootstrap, this `$errorType` should always be warning, danger or success. But since it's a string, I can give `$errorType` an entirely different value. I want to force the usage of the three error types: warning, danger or success. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is one of input validation.

In your context, there's several approaches you can take. The ultimate goal is to check if the input is in a list of accepted values, but the main question is where, when and how to do this.

The most intuitive approach would be to put it right inside the method, eg

```
if (!in_array($input, self::ACCEPTABLE_INPUT)) {
  throw some exception
}
```

An alternative mechanism in the same spirit would be to use assert:

```
assert(in_array($input, self::ACCEPTABLE_INPUT));
```

However this assumes a decent test coverage.

One way which I generally tend to prefer is to model the error type as a value object, eg.

```
final class ErrorType
{
    private const ACCEPTED = ['warning', 'danger', 'success'];
    private $type;
    public function __construct(string $type)
    {
        if (!in_array($type, ErrorType::ACCEPTED) {
             throw some exception
        }
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
}
```

It's a bit more code, but allows you to follow the Single Responsibility Principle.

Your function would simply look like this:

```
public function output($string, ErrorType $errorType) : void
{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-$errorType' role='alert'>$string</div>";
}
```

Comment: Good answer! My upvote :)
Though, visualizing everything as classes does depend on the problem scale at hand

Comment: Very true, each solution has upsides and downsides. The "best" solution is the one where the upsides are more important than the downsides relative to the context of the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Stratadox! Good point on the "error" type success btw.

Comment: @Stratadox One question... You're throwing an error inside the constructor. Isn't the constructor meant just to declare access modifiers and not for logic?

Comment: Access modifiers are eg public protected and private. Inside the constructor, you typically only assign the properties and protect invariants. When people say the constructor is not for logic, they mean "business logic", eg. you're not going to influence other objects or send emails from there. Validation logic is an entirely different matter, though, and can certainly take place in the constructor.

Comment: In the same spirit, simply calling the DateTime constructor like this: `new DateTime('foo');` will produce an Exception because it cannot parse `foo` into a valid date/time combination. The advantage of having objects that protect their own invariants like this, is that you can simply ask for a DateTime object and you can be sure it's going to be a valid date/time combination, not `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

[Throw an Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) if input value of `$errorType` is not a valid value. You can do something like as below:

```
public function output($string, $errorType) : void
{
    // define all possible valid input values for $errorType
    $accepted_error_type = array('warning', 'danger', 'success');

    // throw exception if invalid input
    if (!in_array($errorType, $accepted_error_type) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid errorType in function output. Expected: warning, danger or success. Received: ' . $errorType);
    }

    // Rest of the implementation details come here
    echo "<div class='alert alert-$errorType' role='alert'>$string</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is this the best way to do this in your opinion?

Comment: @user3478148 It is a standard practice across software developement. Programming languages in general does not provide any such ring fencing for function parameters.

Comment: It is one of several ways to solve the problem. Each solution has advantages and drawbacks, the advantage of this one is that it keeps the validation close to the usage, however its downside is that it breaks SRP and potentially leads to a lot of code reuse if you need the same validation elsewhere too.

Comment: @Stratadox true! Creating classes for each and every thing is a very subjective decision. It also depends a lot on the project scale.

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with @Stratadox's answer. I'll upvote your answer anyway since it is a good solution as well.

Comment: @user3478148 yeah it is a better answer. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can let users to give int as `$errorType`. For example 0 for warning, 1 for danger, 2 for success. For other values, you can either set a default value (for example warning) or you can return exception.

```
public function output($string, $errorType)
    {
       $type = "";

       if($errorType == 0)
          $type = "warning";

       else if($errorType == 1)
          $type = "danger";

       else if($errorType == 2)
          $type = "success";

       else
       {
         // You can set a default error type here, if input is incorrect
         // Or you can simply return an exception to inform user about limitations.
       }


        echo "<div class='alert alert-$type' role='alert'>$string</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, looking at the other answers, I feel like this isn't the best way to achieve what I want.